# Como comparar celda contra conjunto de celdas y obtener un valor asociado

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Necesito comparar la fecha de una celda contra una columna que tiene varias fechas, ver con cual coincide y obtener el valor asociado. Aca pongo una imagen para explicarme mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna D es donde necesito colocar la formula, que compare las fechas de la columna A de la hoja 1 con las fechas de la columna A de la hoja 2. Si coincide, necesito multiplicar los valores de la columna C de la hoja 1 por los valores de la columna B de la hoja 2.

Aca otra imagen con un ejemplo para ser mas claro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una pequeña idea que seria algo como:
=SI(ESERROR(COINCIDIR(Hoja1!A4;Hoja2!A2:A32;0));Hoja1!C4*....

donde estan los puntos suspensivos debería ir B3, pero no se como obtener esa celda en la búsqueda de arriba.
Estoy a la espera de algunas ideas, muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es tan complicado como parece, solamente tienes que utilizar la función `BUSCARV` en la que debes colocar en tu parametro de comparacion la fecha, el rango de la `Hoja 2` donde debe ser buscada dicha fecha, el indicador de columna, es decir, cuantas columnas debe moverse para encontrar el valor que deseas retornar y luego multiplicarlo por el valor de la columna C que corresponda, algo así:

```
=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(A2;Hoja2!$A$2:$B$3;2;0);0)*C2
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Yo le puse el `SI.ERROR` en caso que no existiera la fecha o que la celda asociada estuviera vacia que me retorne 0 y en el rango `Hoja2!$A$2:$B$3` ya que hice una prueba con pocos datos, tu debes colocar tu rango completo de la `Hoja 2`. Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, muchas gracias es una solucion genial y bastante sencilla.

Comment: Si te sirvio por favor marcala como aceptada. Saludos.